# How to use bootstrap4 to implement fixed navigation and modules?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How to implement the new version of twitter home page s css html layout. I want to left menu and Navbar and right col is fixed, only body can
scroll, like twitter home page the same.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3"> left menu</div>
      <div class="col-9">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        </nav>
        <div class="row"> <div class="col-9">body</div> 
        <div class="col-3">right col</div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 has a class `sticky-top` can fixed div top.

```
<nav id="main-left-nav"
  class="navbar align-items-start sidebar border-right d-none d-sm-block accordion p-0 topbar sticky-top"></nav>
```

You can see this [demo](https://github.com/jhsfg/twitter-latest-template-html).